# Javascript slider not functioning?

Tags: javascript, jquery, easyslider

I am working on a website and stuck on an annoying problem. Firstly, please visit this page:
http://milabalami.com/saved/2/index.php Hover your mouse over the Menu on the right. You will see that the font changes colour and there is an image covering it.

Now I have implemented this Menu to a WordPress theme: http://milabalami.com/ As you can see when you hover your mouse over the menu, slider doesn't work. Why?

Issue is now resolved here: [Javascript issue with easyslider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4693632/javascript-issue-with-easyslider)

Comment: Update: I get this error on the wordpress page: $("#featured").easySlider is not a function:
http://bit.ly/dLfWQd But I have no idea how to fix it!

Answer (score 4):

On http://miladalami.com/, you are including jQuery **3 times**:

[image]

Each time you load jQuery, you're wiping out all modifications made to the `jQuery.fn` prototype, and thus rendering all plugins loaded before the final one is loaded useless. Remove all but the first jQuery, and update it to use version 1.4.4 instead of 1.4.2, and you should be fine.

Of course, the thinkbox plugin you're using may not function after the upgrade (1.2.4 to 1.4.4 is a rather large upgrade) but you should be able to find alternatives easily.

Comment: Alright, I have removed all jQuery ones, including the thickbox one, and left version 1.4.2 However this did not resolve the issue. Could you please have another look?

Comment: @Alehandro I'm not entirely sure what happened, but it looks like somewhere along the way the `$` variable got overridden. You can try wrapping the custom.js code in an wrapper like this: `(function($){ /* Code here */ }) (jQuery);`

Comment: Sorry Yi Jiang, can you please more in detail how I would wrap the custom.js code and where I put it...? I am quite confused with this.

Comment: If you could kindly update your answer with what I will need to do, that would be very appreciated!